# Describe the Kernel of the map from this polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb R[x]$ denote the ring of all polynomials with real coefficients. The mapping $f(x)\rightarrow f(1)$ is a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb R[x]$ onto $\mathbb R$.

> Question:
>   Describe the kernel of this ring homomorphism.

Recall the definition of kernel of a $\left ( ring \right )$ homomorphism:
$\ker\left ( \varphi \right )=\left \{ f\left ( x \right ) \in\mathbb  R\left [ x \right ] \mid \left [ f\left ( x \right ) \right ]\varphi=0 \right \}$

Now, we define:

Define

$\varphi:R\left [ x \right ]\rightarrow R$

$f\left ( x \right ) \mapsto f\left ( 1 \right )$

I was almost certain the kernel is the trivial kernel but my solution sheet dictates otherwise.

**Hint** is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only possible hint that doesn't give away the answer is a suggestion to apply the definition of kernel that you have written, to this particular homomorphism. It's like putting two and two together.

Comment: I'm not sure how to think about this. I need to find a polynomial f(x)=0. This way, by the Kernel, this polynomial is mapped to the zero element.

Comment: You're missing something. You need a polynomial which, when the homomorphism is applied to it, becomes zero. Now, what the homomorphism does is evaluate the given polynomial at $x = 1$.

Comment: You seem to be self-learning ring theory, and at a good pace too. Keep it up!

Comment: technically I'm in University. But yes, I self-learn using books instead of relying on lectures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** This is primarily a counterexample that shows the kernel to be non-trivial, but it also serves as a strong hint. Let $f(x) = x^2 - 3x + 2$. Then $\varphi(f(x)) = f(1) = 1 - 3 + 2 = 0 \implies f(x) \in \ker \varphi$.

---

**Solution:**

\begin{align*}
\ker \varphi & = \{\, f(x) \in \mathbb R[x] \mid \varphi(f(x)) = 0 \in \mathbb R \,\}\\
& = \{\, f(x) \in \mathbb R[x] \mid f(1) = 0 \,\}\\
& = \{\, f(x) \in \mathbb R[x] \mid (x - 1)\ \text{is a factor of}\ f(x) \,\}\\
& = \{\, (x -1)g(x) \mid g(x) \in \mathbb R[x] \,\}\\
& = \langle x - 1 \rangle
\end{align*}

That is, $\ker \varphi$ is the ideal generated by $x - 1$.

Comment: How were you able to arrive at x-1 being a factor of f(x)?

Comment: @Mathematicing [Factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem).

Comment: And I would suppose that (x-1)g(x) follows from the fact that since (x-1) is a factor of f(x) then f(x) is some multiple g(x) of (x-1)? I apologise if this seem trivial but I am still fairly uncomfortable with ideal generated by 'something'.

Comment: @Mathematicing Exactly, that's the definition of "$(x - 1)$ is a factor of $f(x)$".

Comment: Thanks. 
But how does this leads to <x-1>? If I recall, and it seem wise to hammer this into my cranium, <x-1> is a multiple of (x-1), am I correct? At least, ring notation wise.

Comment: @Mathematicing If you're familiar with vector spaces, then an ideal generated by a set is elements of a (commutative) ring is almost exactly like a subspace spanned by a set of elements of a vector space. And of course, principal ideals (ideals generated by a single element), have an even simpler structure — they consist exactly of all multiples (by all ring elements) of the generator.

Comment: @Mathematicing To be precise, $\langle x - 1 \rangle$ is the set of *all* multiples of $x - 1$, or in other words, $\{\ (x - 1) g(x) \mid g(x) \in \mathbb R[x] \,\}$ — i.e., the (principal) ideal of $\mathbb R[x]$ generated by $x - 1$.